# Boost serialization with recursion

Tags: c++, serialization, recursion, boost

I have a heavily recursive class hierarchy at runtime that I want to serialize. Something like:

Ware -> Warehouse goal -> [Workers on the Way] -> Current Road -> Current Worker -> Current carried ware -> Warehouse goal -> ...
Where "Warehouse goal" may or may not be the same. So the graph can (and does) contain loops.

Currently own serialization stuff is used, recursively diving into the graph with a "already serialized" detection. However due to the deep hierarchy the stack on windows seems to be to small in some occasions.

We also wanted to switch to boost for easier maintenance. How does boost handle this recursive issue? Will I have the same problem with boost as it will try to handle it recursively just like we did before?

What I came up with as an alternative is doing a shallow serialization not serializing member pointers but storing IDs of them and putting them on a list for later serialization. Then do them iteratively until nothing is left. This would still mean, that we got to roll our own algorithm and for deserialization we would need to store pointers to pointers and update them once we deserialized that object.

Comment: Consider using boost::graph. It has support also for boost::serialization

Comment: The "graph" in this application "its a game" is not really a graph but only resembles which instances use or belong to which others. I don't think using boost:graph here would be appropriate. But I haven't used it before so I don't know if there is a good way to use it also for "non-graphs"